# C# Registry how to add multiple values from list

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, registry

I have 2 list strings. First one is for the name of the value and the second one is the data of a value.
I want to set multiple values on a key. The values and data in my code are all in order. So if I call...
`nameval[0]` and `namedata[0]` , it would assign this data to the value that it should be assign to.

My problem is when I use a for loop, it doesn't set the values. But when I set the value of the integer to a specific value, it sets the value.

```
List<string> namevalue = new List<string>();
List<string> namedata =new List<string>();
for (int x = 0; x == namevalue.Count; x++) 
{
    RegistryKey thiskey = Registry.CurrentUser;
    thiskey = thiskey.CreateSubKey("what");
    thiskey.Setvalue(namevalue[x], Convert.FromBase64String(namedata[x]), RegistryValueKind.Binary);
}
```

edit2: i also tried to do this, but same thing happens. it doesn't set the values.

```
        string[] rarted = { "1", "2", "3" };
        string[] rarted2 = { "4", "5", "5" };
        RegistryKey subKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        subKey = subKey.CreateSubKey("somekey", true); 
        for (int i = 0; i >= 2; i++)
        {
            subKey = subKey.OpenSubKey("somekey", true);
            subKey.SetValue(rarted[i], rarted2[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code (include the loop)?

Comment: I am on school, I'll send it when I get home.

Comment: Also, look into using Dictionaries instead of multiple Lists. They're tailormade for key/value pairs. If you have more than one value, make a small class and maintain a List of that instead.

Comment: Your "continue-condition" (`i >= 2`) in your edit2 is still wrong. You're treating it as a "break-condition" (=jump out of the loop). It needs to be `i < 3`.

Comment: Just try a couple of simple for-loops in https://csharppad.com/

Comment: Have you tried it? have you also tried your solution?

Comment: Yes, I tried my loop-suggestion by first replacing the Registry edits with debug messages. It didn't work. Then I added my loop-fix. Then I saw my debug-messages. I haven't checked if the Registry edits work since I'm not that familiar with that part.

Comment: I also strongly suggest debugging your application. You'll have a far better insight into what it's doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for`-loop is faulty:

```
for(a;b;c){
  d;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
a;
while(b)
{
  d;
  c;
}
```

`b` tells you the condition for "should I do one more loop"? Your example never gets into the loop.
So yours should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < namevalue.Count; x++)
```